# Refresh page if loader shown for more than 6 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader

I have a `Loading` component in my React application that simply shows a loading spinner.

I use this whenever I am fetching data. How would I enable the page to reload if the loading component has shown for more than 6 seconds? How would I do this with: `window.location.reload();`

```
import React from 'react';

const Loading = () => (
    <div className="ui active dimmer">
        <div className="ui loader" />
    </div>
);

export default Loading;
```

I use it like this:

```
if(global.isFecthing) {
    return <Loading />;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function that defines the `isFecthing` variable set a timeout after which is refreshes the page?

Comment: Nope, because that function fetches data, we don't want to set a timeout on the actual data fetch.

Comment: It seems like that's exactly what you want to do, refreshing the page will break the data fetch connection. What do you want to do instead?

Comment: what is the http lib you are using ?

Comment: I'm using axios with Redux

Comment: @Joe That won't work because everytime it refreshes the page it makes the call again so you'd end up with a continuous loop of window reloads

Comment: Yes you would if your data source is continuously slow to respond, but that's what you're asking for. Are you able to try and explain a bit more clearly (e.g. step-by-step) exactly what you want to happen?

Comment: I just want to reload the page if the loader is shown for more than 6 seconds, so surely some DOM visibility work needs to be done here rather than just setting a timeout as we need to check for the visibility of the Loading element.

Comment: Ok, if you _"reload the page if the loader is shown for more than 6 seconds"_ then you will run into the _**exact**_ same issue you described above: _"everytime it refreshes the page it makes the call again so you'd end up with a continuous loop"_. There is absolutely no need to monitor the loading div, this should all be handled in the fetch data function and the timeout handled gracefully e.g. telling the user it's failed and prompting them to either refresh or go somewhere else on the site.

Comment: Nice try whoever tried to close this question (and downvoted), next time try actually explaining why it should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to put your fetch initialization function to set a conditional refresh in 6 seconds:

`setTimeout(() => (if (global.isFetching) window.location.reload()), 6000)`

Setting a timeout is non-blocking so it will not block your actual data fetch. The timeout will run in its own thread.